# Android - Loading multiple text files into a RecyclerView

Tags: android, performance, file, io, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a notetaking application for Android, and I have a RecyclerView to display a grid of all the notes. Each note has a respective class called Note.

*The note class knows/has:*

- The filename (Notes title)
- The file path for the note
- A loading method that reads and returns the text inside the file

The recyclerview reads from a ArrayList of Note. The list is populated by a scan of files in the App's note directory, and a Note object is created for each file. I'm trying to find the best way to load the text into the recyclerview, which displays a preview of the notes. I'm wondering if theres a best way, or least stupid way to do this. The ways I can think of doing this are:

- Load every note's content at once during the initial scan and save it as a string in the note class in RAM, the downside being very high RAM usage with alot of notes and text.
- Load the note's text in the Recylerview's **onBindViewHolder** method, but I'm worried if the user is scrolling through notes very fast, and a ViewHolder and its note are unbound before the text is loaded, there could be possible issues here.
- Load each note's text in a threadpool, increases performance but same issue as above.

Is there a best way to do this, or a recommended/standard way to handle alot of files loading dynamically into a recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the first one, then optimise as needed. If theyre just text files, they probably wont take up much memory. If you find they do take up too much memory or take too long to load you can look at strategies to fix that, but dont waste time optimising something before you know its a problem

Comment: There are older Android devices, or budget devices that only have 100-200mb free ram,hence my concern here.

Answer (score 0):

How did you tacke The problem?

I am also making a same Kind of APP, I thing The best option is The second (loading filé contents on bindViewHolder) in an async maner (using asynctask, for example), it's the same BASIC ideia of imagem loaders like Picasso or Glide, you call them on Bind ViewHolder.

If having bad performance you could wrap The async call alongside a caching strategy.